# Generating MAX(field1)+1 on an INSERT with multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have this table (call it `tableA`):

```
id (PK, autoincrement)
field1 (integer)
field2 (integer)
```

And I want to insert some records from another table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2)
SELECT *something*, tableB.field2
FROM tableB;
```

Now, what I need is for `field1` to fill with a new integer in each row, similar to how `id` fills (something like "`MAX(field1)+1`"). Is there a way to do this, maybe using subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that there isn't any concurrency issue here, but I would start with a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_your_table BEFORE INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.field1=case when new.field1 is null then
      coalesce((select max(field1)+1 from your_table),1)
    else new.field1 end
;

insert into your_table (field1, field2) values (10, 1),(11, 2),(12, 3);

select * from your_table;

| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
------------------------
|  1 |     10 |      1 |
|  2 |     11 |      2 |
|  3 |     12 |      3 |

delete from your_table;

insert into your_table (field1, field2) values (10, 1),(11, 2),(12, 3);
insert into your_table (field2) values (4),(5),(6);

select * from your_table;

| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
------------------------
|  1 |     10 |      1 |
|  2 |     11 |      2 |
|  3 |     12 |      3 |
|  4 |     13 |      4 |
|  5 |     14 |      5 |
|  6 |     15 |      6 |
```

See some examples on [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a2c7/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
SET @newVAL = (SELECT MAX(field1) FROM tableA);
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2)
SELECT @newVAL := @newVAL+1, tableB.field2
FROM tableB
```

The idea is to get the MAX value of `field1` first, store it in a variable, and then increment it on each selected row.